# Nested Dictionary collection in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, collections, dictionary

The .NET `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` object allows assignment of key/values like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["1"] = "foo";
dict["2"] = "bar";
```

but I cannot use a Dictionary like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict["F1"]["F2"]["F3"] = "foo";
dict["2"]["X"] = "bar";
```

Is there a collection in .NET which allows me to nest `[]`, or would I have to create my own?

If I have to create my own, how would I do this?

**EDIT:**

It would also be useful if I could have implementations which expect unique keys, like so:

```
dict["F1"]["F2"]["F3"] = "foo";
dict["F1"]["F2"]["F3"] = "bar"; //result is "bar" because "foo" was overridden
```

and an implementation where a key can be used more than once

```
dict["F1"]["F2"]["F3"] = "foo";
dict["F1"]["F2"]["F3"] = "bar"; //result can be "foo" and "bar"
```

Is this possible?

**EDIT (as per Jon Skeet's question):**

I want to use the structure like so (as a very rough example):

```
json["data"]["request"]["name"] = "username";
json["data"]["request"]["pass"] = "password";
```

resolves to

```
{ data: { request: { name: "username", pass: "password" } } }
```

and equally there would be an equivalent for XML etc.

Comment: Do you really need an *arbitrary* (and varying) level of nesting? Perhaps you could describe the bigger picture - there's likely to be a cleaner way of achieving it.

Comment: @JonSkeet, the reason being, I want a structure that allows me to model things like JSON / XML using a .NET collection. See my latest edit

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to use a JSON library (e.g. JSON.NET) which already *has* an appropriate representation?

Comment: @JonSkeet the reason I do not want to use a 3rd party library is because I am writing my own library which covers far more than just JSON etc. Using a library to build a library just seems like a copout! however I can see that using JSON.NET has its benefits, but I don't think it wise in this example.

Comment: My point is that if you were to use a JSON or XML library, you might not need to write an extra dictionary at all...

Comment: @JonSkeet, I totally agree! but 1. I don't really want my library to have any dependencies on anything else other than .NET, and 2. I can't release it to the programming community and say "here look what I made", and then have JSON.NET turn around and say "well actually no, that was us"...if you get my drift?

Comment: You might get somewhere with Dictionary<String,dynamic> , but what you want is begging for a dynamic language IronPython or IronRuby would be goers.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I have provided an answer which seems to work given my test, take a look if you're interested and feel free to pick holes in it...constructive criticism is always appreciated! :-)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, please see my answer...this seems to be what i was looking for...

Comment: @activwerx. Looks pretty elegant. Only issue I see is there's no way to impose any structure when populating it. And you are limited to one type all the way through.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Hi there, just been reading through some of my older questions/comments etc. You mention "you are limited to one type all the way through" - Surely my implementation allows for NestedDictionary<dynamic, dynamic> or NestedDictionary<object, object>, so you could mix types whilst being able to maintain an arbitrarily long nested structure, not so?

Comment: That long ago I've forgot what I was thinking, or even if I did. I might have been thinking that key was the same type in every nested Dictionary. If that's what you are modelling then your solution is elegant.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, haha, I know it was a while ago (and I've since used the structure successfully). But yes, Key can conform to a stricter type (i.e. String, Int32, Guid etc), but you can also use dynamic or object for both Key and Value if necessary.

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel like an apology is necessary here. Clearly 6 years ago I was badly suffering the Dunning Kruger effect.

Comment: @series0ne No apology necessary, I assure you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having a requirement for arbitrarily long nesting, I have come up with the following solution, which as far as I can see, doesn't break, according to my test:

```
public class NestedDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K, NestedDictionary<K, V>>
    {
        public V Value { set; get; }

        public new NestedDictionary<K, V> this[K key]
        {
            set { base[key] = value; }

            get
            {
                if (!base.Keys.Contains<K>(key))
                {
                    base[key] = new NestedDictionary<K, V>();
                }
                return base[key];
            }
        }
    }
```

**TEST:**

```
NestedDictionary<string, string> dict = new NestedDictionary<string, string>();
dict["one"].Value = "Nest level 1";
dict["one"]["two"]["three"].Value = "Nest level 3";
dict["FieldA"]["FieldB"].Value = "Hello World";

Console.WriteLine(dict["one"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(dict["one"]["two"]["three"].Value);
Console.WriteLine(dict["FieldA"]["FieldB"].Value);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using the standard Dictionary, you just have to declare the nesting:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = ...
string test = dict["first"]["second"]

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>> dict = ...
string test = dict["first"]["second"]["third"]

etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The original `Dictionary` COM object which was created to work with vb6 would respond to an attempt to access a non-existent item by creating a new item of type `Dictionary` with the corresponding name.  This approach allows something to be stored to `MyDict["Foo"]["Bar"]` without having to first create `MyDict["Foo"]`.  The problem with this approach is that while one would want to add `"Foo"` to `MyDict` when performing a write to `MyDict["Foo"]["Bar"]`, one would rather not create such an item if one was attempting to e.g. evaluate `MyDict["Foo"]["Bar"].ValueOrDefault(someDefaultValue)`.

I've used such collections, since they can be handy for modeling certain things (conceptually they're a lot like XML documents).  One workable approach is to declare that dictionaries which contain nothing but other dictionaries are considered semantically as non-entities which may be removed at any opportunity.  When implicitly adding a subcollection, set a flag in the item to which it's added it indicating that it should be checked for items that may be deleted (or keep a counter of how many such items may exist).  Then with some reasonable frequency, scan through the dictionaries and remove such "dead" items.

An alternative approach is to have the indexer from the dictionary not return an actual item, but instead return an "ephemeral indexer" type, which keeps a reference to the parent object and has internal methods `GetNestedForReading`, `SetNestedForReading`, `GetValue`, and `SetValue`, which chain back to it.  Then a statement `Foo["Bar"]["Boz"] = "George";` will end up effectively performing `Foo.SetNestedForReading("Bar").SetValue("Boz", "George");` while `z = Foo["Bar"]["Boz"];` will effectively perform `Foo.GetNestedForReading("Bar").GetValue("Boz");`.  Calling `SetNestedForReading` method with a non-existent key will create and return a new nested item; the `GetNestedForReading` method will an immutable "empty" item.  Using this approach will thus avoid creating empty items.

Although the latter approach is more complicated than the former, it has another advantage.  It's possible to have each node to individually hold its collection as either a shared deeply-immutable dictionary or an unshared mutable one; if a `GetNestedForWriting` call sees that the nested object is immutable, it can construct a new shallowly-mutable object holding the same items.  If one defines the cloning method for a mutable node as creating a new immutable node with (immutable) clones of all subnodes, and the cloning method of an immutable node as returning itself, cloning trees that are mostly immutable becomes very cheap.  If one had a newly-cloned (thus immutable) four-level tree with sixteen items on each level (65,536 leaf nodes total) and all the nodes were shared-immutable, updating a leaf node would only require replacing one leaf and four other nodes with mutable ones.  Cloning the tree again would only require creating new immutable objects for the nodes which had been replaced with mutable ones (e.g. copying five things).  Although one would have the convenience of a fully-mutable tree, one would have the efficiency advantages of an immutable one.

The biggest "problem" I see with this approach is that to avoid some weird behaviors one must require the use of syntax like `MyDict["Foo"]["Bar"].Value = "George"`.  If implicit conversion operators were used to avoid that requirement, someone would expect a statement like `var st = MyThing["Foo"]["Bar"];` to define `st` as a `string` snapshot of whatever `MyThing["Foo"]["Bar"]` holds at that moment; instead it would define it as something that will index `MyThing["Foo"]["Bar"]`.  If one had to use `.Value` to read or write strings from such a type, the fact that the variable wasn't a string would be apparent.  If one used implicit operators to allow such assignments, the behavior would be odd.  It's too bad there's no way a function can specify "do not allow this return value to be used for type inference".

Incidentally, it's possible to have the indexer type be a class or a generic struct.  If it's a class, an access to `foo["Bar"]["boz"]["baz"]...` nested `N` deep would likely require the creation of `N` temporary heap objects.  If it's a generic struct, it would entail the creation of `N` structs, but the more-deeply-nested structs would get bigger.  For reasonable levels of nesting, generic structs would probably be slightly more efficient, but classes would probably be easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Dictionary` as `TValue`:

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
var dict3 = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

for example:

```
var dict =
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
        {
            {
                "F1", new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                {"F2", "foo"}
                            }
                }
        };


dict["F1"]["F2"] = "bar";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide on either supporting a fixed number of string keys to look up, or provide a more general key mechanism if the number of keys can vary. For the first case try the following:

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> dict =
    Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();
dict["F1"]["F2"] = "foo";
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>> dict2 =
    Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();
dict2["F1"]["F2"]["F3"] = "bar";
```

For the second case, you could do the following:

```
Dictionary<string[],string> dict = new Dictionary<string[],string>(new MyEqualityComparer());
dict[new string[] {"F1","F2"}] = "foo";
dict[new string[] {"F1","F2","F3"}] = "bar";
```

where the class MyEqualityComparer would be something like:

```
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<string[]>
{
    public int GetHashCode(string[]item)
    {
         int hashcode = 0;
         foreach (string s in item)
         { 
             hashcode |= s.GetHashCode();
         }
         return hashcode;
    }

    public bool Equals(string [] a, string [] b)
    {
         if (a.Length != b.Length)
             return false;
         for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
         {
             if (a[i] != b[i])
                 return false;
         }
         return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, your case is good place to use `DynamicObject`. I'll create an example  for json using `Dictionary<string, object>` internally.

Same idea can be used for xml also.

```
string json = @"{""Name"":""Joe"",
                 ""Age"":30,
                 ""Address"":{ ""City"":""NY"" }}";

dynamic dynObj = new DynamicJson(json);

Console.WriteLine(dynObj.Name);
Console.WriteLine(dynObj.Age);
Console.WriteLine(dynObj.Address.City);
```

--

```
public class DynamicJson : DynamicObject
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _Dict;

    public DynamicJson(string json)
    {
        _Dict = (Dictionary<string, object>)new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(json); 
    }

    DynamicJson(Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        _Dict = dict;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        object obj;
        if (!_Dict.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out obj)) return false;

        if (obj is Dictionary<string, object>)
        {
            result = new DynamicJson((Dictionary<string, object>)obj);
        }else
        {
            result = obj;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```