# Convert XML string into equivalent

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML like this:

```
<roottag>
    <tag1>.....</tag1>
    <tag2>.....</tag2>
    <tag3>
        <tag3.1>.....</tag3.1>
        <tag3.2>.....</tag3.2>
   </tag3>
    <tag4>
        <tag4.1>
            <tag4.1.1>......</tag4.1.1>
        </tag4.1>
   </tag4>
</roottag>
```

I want to convert this XML into a form which can be easily traversed and also maintain the the hierarchy in the XML. In php, there is `Nested Associative Array` which can be used. In C# How can I accomplish this  ?

Comment: `XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("xmlstring");`  You can then use LINQ to XML to traverse/navigate the XML.

Comment: You also may use `XSLT`

Comment: You can deserialize the XML into object.[This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722492/xml-string-deserialization-into-c-sharp-object) may help you.

Comment: I basically want to convert it into some sort of `Associative Array`. Here in C#, I guess I can use `Dictionary`, but can I use the nested `Dictionary` to maintain the hierarchy also ?

Comment: @Mayank Nested dictionary is a good option.Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543094/nested-dictionary-collection-in-net) link.But you have to declare the nesting first.

Comment: The hierarchy of XML gets changed from time to time. I cannot declare the nesting first, it has to be at runtime.

Comment: Why can't you use a List<YourCutomClass> to do this?

Comment: @VimalCK....thanks for the suggestion, but I am not aware about how to use the `List<MyCustomClass>`. Can you please enlighten me on this.