# merge two json files into one

Tags: c#, json

I have two Json file. One will be subset of the other. I have to merge them. For example,

```
1.
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "C": "D"
    }
  }
}

2.
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "E": "F"
    }
  }
}
```

resultant json (1 + 2) file should be

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "C": "D"
      "E": "F"   
    }
  }
}
```

I am using NewtownSoft to read from Json file and tried to deserialize into nested dictionary but value is not populating on the resultant json file.

```
public class NestedDictionary<K, V> : Dictionary<K, NestedDictionary<K, V>>
    {
        public V Value { set; get; }

        public new NestedDictionary<K, V> this[K key]
        {
            set { base[key] = value; }

            get
            {
                if (!base.Keys.Contains<K>(key))
                {
                    base[key] = new NestedDictionary<K, V>();
                }
                return base[key];
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how I am using nested dictionary, I took it from ([Nested Dictionary collection in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543094/nested-dictionary-collection-in-net/12546090#12546090))

I changed my approach by using Dictionary instead of NestedDictionary. Here is the method which is merging the two json files

```
public static void MergeJsonFile()
{
string[] json2 = parent.ToArray();
Dictionary<string,object> json2Data = (Dictionary<string, object>) parents.Reverse().Aggregate((object)null, (a, s) => a == null ? (object)s : new Dictionary<string, object> { { s, a } });

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json2Data, Formatting.Indented);


    string json1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\changes.json");

    Dictionary<string, object> existingChangedDataDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(savedChangedData);
    Dictionary<string, object> temp = existingChangedDataDictionary, prevDictionary = null;

    int x = 0;
    List<string> keys = new List<string>(existingChangedDataDictionary.Keys);

    while (keys.Contains(parents[x]))
    {
        prevDictionary = temp;
        temp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(temp[parents[x]].ToString());
        json2Data = (Dictionary<string, object>)json2Data[parents[x]];
        keys = new List<string>(temp.Keys);
        x++;
    }

    var updatedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existingChangedDataDictionary, Formatting.Indented);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Desktop\changes.json",updatedData);
}
```

But the resultant json file comes as

```
{
  "A": {
    "B": {
      "C": "D"
       },
     "B":{
      "E": "F"   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But you don't really have a `Dictionary<K, NestedDictionary<K,V>>` but rather a `Dictionary<string, object>` where object could be a `Dictionary<string, object>` again (until you come up to A.B.C where the value is just a string

Comment: What happens if there are keys available in one dictionary but not in the other?

Comment: I can think of one approach, convert both JSON to class.. and make a final class by using two classes using reflection (by getting properties) . and then convert the final class to JSON.

Comment: I tried using Dictionary<string, object> but then the second level became JToken instead of dictionary<string, object> @Icepickle

Comment: resultant will have both the keys in it @Icepickle

Comment: That would be a very expensive approach because what I have showed here is just a small part of it @viveknuna

Comment: using nested dictionary is not mandatory for me, I just showed here for more clarification